# How can I make this query faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I'm running this query on an Oracle DB:

`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db.table WHERE columnA = 'VALUE' AND ROWNUM < 2`

There is no index on columnA, and the table has many many thousands of lines (possibly millions). There's about twenty values that should be returned, so it's not a huge set being returned. However, because it triggers a full table scan it takes eons. How can I make it go faster?

**Note:** I'm not a DBA so I have limited access to the database and can't implement restructuring, or adding indexes, or get rid of old data.

Comment: Should we assume that you cannot create an index on `columnA` to make the query more efficient?  And, just so I understand, you only want to optimize the latter query, not the former query, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the existence of a row, not the number of times it appears, then this would be more appropriate:

```
SELECT 1 
  FROM DB.TABLE
 WHERE ColumnA = 'VALUE'
   AND ROWNUM = 1
```

That will stop the query as fast as possible once a row's been found; however, if you need it to go faster, that's what indexes are for.

Test Case:

```
create table q8806566
( id        number not null,
  column_a  number not null,
  padding   char(256),  -- so all the rows aren't really short
  constraint pk_q8806566 primary key (id) 
    using index tablespace users
)
tablespace users;

insert into q8806566 -- 4 million rows
  (id, column_a, padding)
with generator as
(select --+ materialize
        rownum as rn from dba_objects 
  where rownum <= 2000)
select rownum as id, mod(rownum, 20) as column_a, 
       v1.rn as padding
  from generator v1
       cross join generator v2;

commit;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (ownname => user, tabname => 'q8806566');
```

The data for column_A is well distributed, and can be found in the first few blocks for all values, so this query runs well:

```
SELECT 1    
  FROM q8806566
 WHERE Column_A = 1 
   AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Sub .1 sec execution time and low I/O - on the order of 4 I/Os.  However, when looking for a value that's NOT present, things change alarmingly:

```
SELECT 1    
  FROM q8806566
 WHERE Column_A = 20
   AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

20-40 seconds of execution time, and over 100,000 I/Os.

However, if we add the index:

```
create index q8806566_idx01 on q8806566 (column_a) tablespace users;
exec dbms_stats.gather_index_stats (ownname => user, indname => 'q8806566_idx01');
```

We get sub .1 second response time and single-digit I/Os from both queries.

Comment: So there's no way to speed it up? Other than indexes?

Comment: @Malfist - Nope. Unless `ColumnA` has an index on it, the database server will have no choice but to scan the table and stop once a row's been found. If you build a non-clustered index on `ColumnA`, the database will quickly seek that row and then give you a 1 or an empty result.

Comment: Exactly what other technique do you think would be more appropriate than the one designed for it?  One could, if needed, build an on-commit materialized view, but that's a bigger-hammer approach, and requires much more extensive database changes.

Comment: I know indexes were designed for this reason, but getting the DBA's to add an index typically means I'll have to wait at least four months for the change to be approved and implemented.

Comment: Show them how much time's being wasted.  How frequently does this statement run?  If it runs 1000 times a day, and the difference in time is .01 seconds versus 10 seconds, ask them why they're willing to waste 1,000,000 seconds per day of user time and I/O bandwidth.

Comment: It's actually an old query in an old system that's being modernized, I doubt it's been ran in years. But QA wants to test the modernization, which would mean running the new query (and some extras) a few hundred times...

Comment: indexes would definitely modernize your system

Comment: @Malfist - Four months to get a simple, one-column non-clustered index added?! I'm glad I don't work where you do :\

Comment: @Eric, 3-4 releases a year, no off-cycle releases without a production emergency, which this isn't. I'm sure they had their reasons when they implemented that system, but I think it's a bit silly. Especially for things like this that don't really have side effects.

Comment: @AdamMusch your first recommended query takes ~18 minutes to run and match the data you provide (sub second response for present value, orders of magnitude greater for non-present values).

Comment: As you didn't create a unique index the hint `/*+ first_rows(1) */` may speed this up slightly as well...